# JavaScript Clock Not displaying Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, xcode, widget

I'm having an issue where I have a digital sign and it accepts embedded HTML. I created a widget for it to display a clock, I tried downloading one and they never worked for some reason so made my own. The issue that I am having is that the clock does not display the correct time. I got it so the numbers display correctly but the issue that I am seeing now is that it will dsiplay AM instead of PM. I would appreciate any help, not sure if the logic is right or if I used the wrong condition statements. Any help would be awesome, Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function updateTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    var p;
    if (minutes < 10){
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10){
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    if (hours >= 12){
        p = "PM";   //could not get this in it's own if statement w/o breaking it
        hours = (hours - 12);
    }
    if (hours == 0) {
        hours = (hours + 12);
    }else {
        p = "AM";
    }

    var v = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + p;

    setTimeout("updateTime()", 1000);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML= v;
}
updateTime();
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#time {
    font-size: 5em;
}
</style>
<div><span id="time"></span></div>
```

Comment: try to change this line `setTimeout("updateTime()", 1000);` to `setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);`

Comment: @Morpheus, I tried that, and I got the same issue where it should display as PM it displays at AM.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PJhjQ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was almost right, there is just one little mistake you're making. when you check if `hours` is greater than `12`, `p` is `PM` **else** `p` should be `AM`. You can solve this by setting `p` to `AM` at the beginning of the function, of moving the `else` you already have up right after the check.

This Fiddle will demonstrate a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/s2R9y/

```
if (hours >= 12) {
    p = "PM";
    hours = (hours - 12);
} else {
    p = "AM";
}
```

---

The `setTimeOut` function has been fixed aswell, so it actually worked:

```
setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
```

Comment: I was operating under the assumption that you couldn't write an if statement without an else at the end, this worked for me thanks a lot!

Comment: @GeorgeOffley But you were using some if-statements without an else in your code already! I'm glad it helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

change your IFs to:

```
if (hours >= 12) {
    p = "PM";
    hours = (hours>12) ? (hours - 12) : 12;
}
else
{
    if (hours == 0)
        hours = 12;
    p = "AM";
}
```

Comment: That worked except that when I ran it with my computer clock at 12noon it displays as AM and not PM.